# Grouped CollectionView in .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, data-binding, maui

I have a ObservableRangeCollection Persons in my ViewModel which is bound in XAML to a CollectionView via ItemsSource. The DataTemplate is of Type Person, so they can be displayed.

Currently, I don’t know how I would do the grouping which is provided via IsGrouped-Option in the CollectionView.

How would I introduce the different Groups based on the first Letter of the Name of a Person, so that I have a Group „A“ with all Persons whose Name starts with letter „A“.

My ObservableRangeCollection is filled from values of a SQLite database which does not have groups, just the details for a Person.

Comment: Have you read the docs?  They have examples of how to modify the data to support grouping.  There are also many examples of grouping using Xamarin Forms that should also apply in MAUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to **group** the person based on `first character` of the name of the **Person**, you can refer to the sample code below:

**SAMPLE CODE:**

**XAML:**

```
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsGrouped="True"> 

        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <Label FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Gray" Text="{Binding Name}" />

            </DataTemplate>

        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <VerticalStackLayout>

                    <Label

                       Text="{Binding Name}"

                       FontAttributes="Bold" />

                
                </VerticalStackLayout>

            </DataTemplate>

        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>
```

**VIDEMODEL:**

```
public class MainPageViewModel 
    {

        public List<Person> origin_list { get; set; } = new List<Person>();

        public List<Grouped_list> Persons { get; set; } = new List<Grouped_list>();



        public MainPageViewModel()
        {

           //Pseudo data, you may retrieve the data from database and assign to it
            origin_list.AddRange(new List<Person> {

               new Person("Allan", "Male"),
                new Person("Alex", "Male"),
                new Person("Klay", "Male"),
                new Person("Kate", "Female"),
                new Person("Bob", "Male"),
                new Person("Besley", "Male"),
                new Person("John", "Male"),
                new Person("Fiona", "Female")

            });

            //Group by the first letter
             var dict = (origin_list.OrderBy(x=>x.Name)).GroupBy(o => o.Name.Substring(0,1)).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());

            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<Person>> item in dict)
            {

                Persons.Add(new Grouped_list(item.Key, new List<Person>(item.Value)));
            }


        }

       
    }
```

**Grouped_list.cs**

```
    public class Grouped_list : List<Person> 
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Grouped_list(string name, List<Person> person):base(person)
        { 
            Name = name;
        
        }
    }
```

**MODEL:**

```
    public class Person 
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Gender { get; set; }  

        public Person(string name, string gender)
        {
            
            Name = name;
            Gender = gender;
        
        }

    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replies and the hint that I need a list in list combination. I tried it as in the Example above with Group_list. Unfortunately, my XAML can not access „Name“ in the DataTemplate. The list itself is not underlined but the Name is underlined. In XAML I use an x:DataType Header to my ViewModel in which I should be able to Access the Grouped_list and then also Access the Name for the group. Is there a way, I can debug or see how I can access this Name?

Comment: Thanks for your response, the sample above should also work if you tried it. Can you make sure if you have created a Model: Person with Name properties?

Comment: I had to introduce x:DataType=„viewModels:GroupedPeopleItemList“ in my DataTemplate of the CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate:      <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate><DataTemplate x:DataType=„viewModels:GroupedPeopleItemList“><Label FontSize=„18“ FontAttributes=„Bold“ BackgroundColor=„Gray“ Text=„{Binding GroupName}“ /></DataTemplate></CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>    so that I could reference my GroupName defined in my public partial Class GroupedPeopleItemList : List<People> in my ViewModels-NS

Comment: Thanks for the response, is `GroupName` is a property in `People`? BTW, if above answer is helpful, please accept it as answe as it will help others who have similar issue! Thanks in advance!

Comment: GroupName is a Property of the GroupedPeopleItemList. Maybe the problem was, that this List is defined in the Namespace of the ViewModel as a separate class and could not be referenced without the x:DataType declaration in the viewModel Namespace?

Comment: Yes, it could be the issue as you pointed out. If possible, you can create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link, I can help you take a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you. Download ListView example => Grouping:
[Github](https://github.com/syncfusion/maui-demos/tree/master/MAUI/ListView/SampleBrowser.Maui.ListView/Samples/ListView/Grouping)

[image]

Comment: This looks very good  Nice user Interface with all the Icons

Comment: always please happy to help

Answer (score 0):

> My ObservableRangeCollection is filled from values of a SQLite database which does not have groups, just the details for a Person.

You speak as if this is something that has to remain like that. Obviously if you do not want to make groups, you wont be able to use grouping. So if you plan to keep it that way, I consider this question answered.

If you decide to create groups after all, the first thing you should do is bind to list of lists.

The outer list is simple. The inner list has property, that is used for grouping, and extends list.

To create those, you can modify the way you read them from the database, but if you do not want or know how to, and want to keep current reading, there is a way to use LINQ, in a way making another query for grouping, in similar way:

```
foreach( IGrouping<string, Model> group in NonGroupedList.GroupBy(s => s.Letter))
    MyGroups.Add(new MyGroup(group.key, group.ToList()));
```

Comment: This was also a good hint that I need an outer and an inner list to realize this! Thanks

Comment: @OXO do what Alex answered. It is perfect example for getting things going. And once you have something working, you can tinker with it.